# JSON and C# System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer alternative

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization

I was using JavaScriptSerializer to handle JSON serialization, but because of some unforeseen problems ([my bad luck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581813/sql-server-clr-load-assembly-failed)) I have to use something else.

All I need from serializer looks lie this:

```
string json = "..."
JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Dictionary<string, Object> o = ser.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Object>>(json);
```

So I end up with a dictionary that contains other dictionaries/arrays/objects that represents json hierarchical structure. I already have a code that does some analysis on data structured like that, and I don't want to change that part.

Which JSON parser for C# can provide such functionality?

Comment: did u found one? would u plz share?

Answer (score 1):

you can use json.net or fastjson opensource libraries to perform this task in a faster and more efficient way than using the built in .net serializer.

json.net - http://json.codeplex.com/

fastJson - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/159450/fastJSON