# Loading assembly into SQL Server 2017 database

Tags: .net, sql-server, sqlcl

I am trying to load a CLR assembly `Split.dll` into a SQL Server 2017 database:

CREATE ASSEMBLY Split 
   FROM 'D:\SqlClr\split.dll' 
   WITH Permission_set = SAFE
   GO

I've built this assembly using Visual Studio 2019. But I get this error:

> Msg 10301, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Assembly 'Split' references assembly 'netstandard, version=2.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51.', which is not present in the current database. SQL Server attempted to locate and automatically load the referenced assembly from the same location where referring assembly came from, but that operation has failed (reason: 2 (The system cannot find the file specified.)). Please load the referenced assembly into the current database and retry your request.

I've tried to do the same with SQL Server 2014 and Visual Studio 2015. Actually I've used the same C# code to get DLL and the same SQL statement (showed above) to load it. In this case everything worked well.

I've read [Sql Server CLR load assembly failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581813/sql-server-clr-load-assembly-failed) but when I was trying to loading `netstandard.dll`:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY netstandard 
AUTHORIZATION dbo 
FROM 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\netstandard.dll' 
WITH Permission_set = SAFE
GO
```

I get this error:

> Msg 6212, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   CREATE ASSEMBLY failed because method 'EnsureEventSourceIndexAvailable' on type 'System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventCounterGroup'  in safe assembly 'System.Diagnostics.Tracing' is storing to a static field. Storing to a static field is not allowed in safe assemblies.

Can anybody help me? Why did the same code work well in SQL Server 2014 and DLL built in Visual Studio 2015 and I've got a problem now (SQL Server 2017, Visual Studio 2019)? What is the way of fixing this problem?

Comment: See this warning at the Microsoft site: [warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-assembly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Does your function split strings? There is now a native function that does this (although not sure how fast it is)

Comment: @Luuk thank a lot for your responce, but I've tried EXEC sp_configure 'clr strict security',0;

Comment: The option @Nick.McDermaid is the best, it avoid problems when migrating to version 2021 

Comment: See if the target framework changed from .NET Framework to .NetStandard or .NET Core in the newly compiled assembly.    I also have to wonder if the error means exactly what it says - that the assembly entry exit - calling point is static "global" and not instance specific.  So different SQL Spids would be writing to the exact same instance and therefore be corrupting and overwriting themselves at runtime across Sql Server Spids.

Comment: @SqlSurfer thanks, I've change target framework to .Net Framework and my problem is solved

Answer (score 2):

Just for speedy clarification as I must have bounced off of this question a couple times in my own search for a solution. The answer is actually given in the comments above... I just didn't read the comments at first. The problem was that I had selected the wrong Framework. The .Net Standard Framework shows at the top of the list... the correct framework is way down the list so it is easily (at least for me) missed:[image]

Comment: Nice one - this was my problem, too (confusing .NET _Standard_ with .NET **Framework**).  This answer explains the difference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76748330/confusion-about-net-vs-net-core-vs-net-standard-vs-net-framework.