Example of the utility of the `G9` format specifier in C# for round-tripping floating-point numbers?
I'm trying to understand the practical utility of the G9 format specifier in C# when dealing with round-tripping floating-point numbers.
The book C#12 in a nutshell mentions that G9 is helpful to avoid precision loss when converting a float to a string and back to a float (page 324). But I can't find an example that shows a case where G9 formatting succeeds in preserving equality, while default formatting would fail.
For example:
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        float originalNumber = 0.1f;

        string defaultFormatted = originalNumber.ToString();

        float defaultRoundTrip = float.Parse(defaultFormatted);
        Console.WriteLine("Default Formatting:");
        Console.WriteLine("Original: " + originalNumber);
        Console.WriteLine("Formatted: " + defaultFormatted);
        Console.WriteLine("Round-trip Equal: " + (originalNumber == defaultRoundTrip));

        string g9Formatted = originalNumber.ToString("G9");

        float g9RoundTrip = float.Parse(g9Formatted);
        Console.WriteLine("\nG9 Formatting:");
        Console.WriteLine("Original: " + originalNumber);
        Console.WriteLine("Formatted: " + g9Formatted);
        Console.WriteLine("Round-trip Equal: " + (originalNumber == g9RoundTrip));
    }
}

Gives me
Default Formatting:
Original: 0.1
Formatted: 0.1
Round-trip Equal: True

G9 Formatting:
Original: 0.1
Formatted: 0.100000001
Round-trip Equal: True

I was expecting something of the sort:
Default Formatting:
Original: 0.1
Formatted: 0.100000000001
Round-trip Equal: False

G9 Formatting:
Original: 0.1
Formatted: 0.1
Round-trip Equal: True


The documentation says that the default G format uses the “Smallest round-trippable number of digits to represent the number” (G7 for float, G15 for double), but this may have changed between .NET versions.

@dan04 Actually, the documentation says that it currently uses as many digits as needed, not G7/G15. The text in the parentheses refers to .Net Framework, which is the old .Net before .Net Core and the current .Net which is called just .Net (confusing, I know).

@relatively_random Is the current .Net the same as .Net Core? I never understand. I understand that .Net Framework is the "old" version that only runs on Windows but I don't know if there is a difference between .Net and .Net Core.

Here's an answer to that question around here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76748398/4247453

One more slightly unrelated comment. If you care about round-tripping, you're probably storing those floats for future machine use, not just human readability. In that case, I highly recommend using the invariant culture, otherwise your format will change when your users speak a different language: ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) or ToString(format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).

Your observations are correct. Calling Single.ToString without any arguments can indeed roundtrip the number.
From the documentation of ToString(),

The ToString() method formats a Single value in the default ("G", or general) format of the current culture.

From standard numeric format strings, it is said that for float, "G" on its own without any precision will use as much precision as needed to round-trip the number.

If the precision specifier is omitted or zero, the type of the number determines the default precision, as indicated in the following table.




Numeric Type
Default Precision




Single
Smallest round-trippable number of digits to represent the number (in .NET Framework, G7 is the default)



Note that it does say that it will use G7 on .NET Framework, and this is possibly why the book author made that remark about using G9.
See also this very old answer that quotes the documentation for Single.ToString(), which is different from what it says today.

By default, the return value only contains 7 digits of precision although a maximum of 9 digits is maintained internally.
If you require more precision, specify format with the "G9" format specification, which always returns 9 digits of precision, or "R", which returns 7 digits if the number can be represented with that precision or 9 digits if the number can only be represented with maximum precision.

So this purpose of "G9" was actually documented.

To be technical, the internal precision of System.Single (aka float) is 24 binary digits, which is equivalent to 7.225 decimal digits.

So there are no cases where G9 formatting succeeds in preserving equality, while default formatting would fail?

@FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows That is correct, unless you are using .NET Framework.

Pro tip: with modern computing power you can actually easily test every possible float value. Doubles are still out of reach, unfortunately.
Here's some quick and dirty parallel code which runs in ~2 minutes on my machine.
With the G7 format, 67% of possible values don't round trip (was the default in .Net Framework). With G8, 1.5% don't round trip. With G9, there are no errors (should be the current default). And these values are underestimates because I couldn't be bothered to account for NaNs.
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;

var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

var totalErrors = 0L;
const string format = "G7";

Parallel.For(0, Environment.ProcessorCount, partition =>
{
    var localErrors = 0;

    // For and while loops are awkward around MaxValue so using
    // a do-while which checks for overflow after increment.
    uint i = (uint)partition;
    do
    {
        if (!CheckIndividual(i))
            ++localErrors;

        if (i % 10_000_000 == 0 && i != 0)
        {
            long processed = i + 1;
            var elapsed = sw.Elapsed;
            var remaining = (4294967296 - processed) * elapsed / processed;
            Console.WriteLine($"Inspected {i}, elapsed {elapsed}, remaining {remaining}");
        }

        i += (uint)Environment.ProcessorCount;
    } while (i >= (uint)Environment.ProcessorCount);

    _ = Interlocked.Add(ref totalErrors, localErrors);
});

Console.WriteLine($"Total errors: {totalErrors}");
Console.WriteLine($"Done after: {sw.Elapsed}");


static bool CheckIndividual(uint i)
{
    var f = BitConverter.UInt32BitsToSingle(i);

    // Ignoring NaNs and infinities.
    if (!float.IsFinite(f))
        return true;

    var s = f.ToString(format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    var f2 = float.Parse(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    if (BitConverter.SingleToUInt32Bits(f2) != i)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine($"Failed to round trip {s} (0x{i:x8})");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}


Interesting! I tried f.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); which should call G9 which should be the current default and I do get 0 errors. Satisfying to see that everything checks out.
